# How to access members of wrapper class from member which is wrapped in class

Tags: c++, wrapper

For ex. I got:
"wrapper.h"

```
class wrapper : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    Wrapped_class m_class;

    private:
    QTimer* m_timer;
}
```

"Wrapped_class.h"

```
class Wrapped_class
{
public:
Wrapped_class();
public slots:
f(); // slot which is called when m_timer send signal timeout()

}
```

"Wrapped_class.cpp"

```
Wrapped_class::Wrapped_class()
{
QOBject::connect(wrapper::m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT( f()))
}
```

I get error that wrapper::m_timer in not accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `pointer` or `reference` to the class to access it's `non static` members. Pass a `pointer` to the wrapped class when it's being wrapped

add something like this to your `Wrapped_class`:

```
void Wrapped_class::setWrapper(wrapper *w)
{
    m_wrapper = w;
}
```

and call this function when the object is being wrapped. Initialize `m_rapper` to `nullptr` in constructor

Comment: I made m_timer static, but still get error that it is inaccessible

Comment: @spin_eight: because it's marked `private`. And are you sure you want a `static` timer ? It means there will be just one timer for all your wrappers

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want. Yes it is marked private, but *private members of wrapper can be accessed by other members of wrapper*, am I right?

Comment: @spin_eight: no. Private members can be accessed only by `wrapper` or friends of `wrapper`

Comment: Are sure? For ex. I got class which has as private members other classes and that classes can access private members of class in which they are wrapped

Comment: @spin_eight: No, it's not possible in C++. Member objects know nothing about the composite object if you don't write so (by passing a pointer or reference).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your intent and the design of your system, you can choose:

1. Pass a pointer or reference of "wrapper" class to "wrapped" class. Be ware, you have to define wrapper class as a `friend` in order to access `private` member.
2. Write a member function of "wrapper" class to deal with the interaction between two classes. (This does not really conform to your restriction, but it is a design alternative.)

Answer (score 0):

`m_timer` is not a static member so you cant access it like that. In `Wrapped_class.cpp` you need the instance of wrapped class to use it

Answer (score 0):

Besides the problem with `wrapper::m_timer` not being static, it is also *private* which means that `Wrapped_class` can't access it. You need to make `Wrapped_class` a friend of `wrapper` for it to access private members.

Comment: Possibly, it would be better to add a `getter` instead of making a `friend`